# How to upload image with angular components using python selenium

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

My automation script needs to upload an image to the webpage but I can't seem to upload the image using the normal send_keys method. I suspect it has something to do with the Angular components but I'm not sure how to access them using Selenium webdriver.

I have tried the following:
[Automate file upload using Selenium and ng-file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590676/automate-file-upload-using-selenium-and-ng-file-upload)
and [How to upload file using python+selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011606/how-to-upload-file-using-pythonselenium)

These don't seem to have the solution I'm looking for.

`<button class="md-raised choose-file md-button md-ink-ripple ng-empty ng-valid" type="button" ng-transclude="" ngf-select="" accept="image/*" ng-model="vm.uploader.original" aria-invalid="false">Choose file</button>`

I don't have any errors because I can successfully locate the element but the image is not uploaded/sent.

```
file_input.send_keys("/location/of/image/profile_student.jpg")
```

Comment: Do you have any input field beside the `Choose file` button? Or you are clicking on `Choose file` button and its pop up windows form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium file upload without <input type="file"> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888388/selenium-file-upload-without-input-type-file-element)

Comment: @KunduK no, I only have the choose file button. Once you click it, it opens the "open file" pop up box.

Comment: Ok.To access windows object you need to use autoit with selenium.

Answer (score 2):

To handle windows object you can use `autoit` However there is Python binding for `AutoItX3.dll`

You need to install `PyAutoIt` using pip.

> pip install -U pyautoit

You need to import autoit on your python scripts.

> import autoit

Click on the `chose file` button first.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button'][contains(.,'Choose file')]").click()
```

Then add the following code with the `relevant file path`

```
filepath="C:\\filelocation\\filename.jpg"
autoit.win_wait_active("File Upload",5)
if autoit.win_exists("File Upload"):
   autoit.control_send("File Upload","Edit1",filepath+"{ENTER}")
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Will this work on mac? It will only be used in a mac/linux environment.

Comment: I don't use mac or Linux.However worth give it a try.let me know how it goes?

Comment: The installation failed and after doing some research it seems like it only works on Windows.

Comment: @LeroySharp : just check are you able to install `pip install pypiwin32` this?

Comment: Using AutoIt is a hack, selenium already supports file uploads, you just need to find the <input type="file"> element and populate that.  If one doesn't exist you need to hook into the JavaScript implementation using a JavascriptExecutor.  You should never use AutoIt, it's brittle, not cross platform compliant and only works on the local machine.